# Selenium cursor focus on field

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating tests (in Firefox) for a web app.

Depending on what field the cursor is over, a different help screen will appear. But when creating tests for those help screens, i cant get Selenium to focus on the particular field i want.
I've tried using fireEvent, click, select, and type in order to get the focus to stay on the field i require in order to load that particular help screen but i've had no luck.

Does anyone have ideas on how this can be solved. Or how i can work around it?

Comment: What are you using? Selenium IDE or Selenium RC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selenium2 [AdvancedUserInteractions API](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions):

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 builder.moveToElement(someElement).build().perform();
```

Comment: Currently I am using Selenium RC. Now I'll be seriously considering to switching to Selenium Webdriver where I can access advanced functionality as MouseHover effects. Thank you for the hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding of your question is correct, you wanted to display different help screens for differnt elements,
o.k here it is, if the message of the screen is displayed as a tool tip and the styling is taken care by mouseover event
selenium.mouseOver(locator) and then [ Thread.sleep(1000) ] and then use
selenium.mouseOut(locator)
 try with this.if you don't get it and if my understanding of your question is wrong please post it.

you must investigate how that screen is being is displayed. and try to post all that code